# C++ class operator overloads don't work with std::sort

Tags: c++, sorting, operator-overloading, operators, std

So I have been been trying to build a median generator that takes in fractions and generates the median however it seems like currently I am unable to sort a vector of my self defined RationalNumber class. I have overloaded a number of the operators ( * + / ==  etc etc) however they don't seem to work when called inline elsewhere.

```
RationalNumber RationalNumber::operator*(const RationalNumber& r)
{
    RationalNumber result(numerator * r.numerator, denominator * r.denominator);
    result.reduceFraction();
    return result;
}   

RationalNumber RationalNumber::operator*(int x)
{
    RationalNumber result(numerator * x, denominator);
    result.reduceFraction();
    return result;
}

RationalNumber RationalNumber::operator/(const RationalNumber& r)
{
    RationalNumber result(numerator * r.denominator, denominator * r.numerator);
    result.reduceFraction();
    return result;
}

RationalNumber RationalNumber::operator/(int x)
{
    RationalNumber result(numerator, denominator * x);
    result.reduceFraction();
    return result;
}
bool RationalNumber::operator<(const RationalNumber& r)
{
    if(this->floatingPoint < r.floatingPoint)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

bool RationalNumber::operator<(int x)
{
    if(floatingPoint < (double) x)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

bool RationalNumber::operator>(const RationalNumber& r)
{
    if(floatingPoint > r.floatingPoint)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool RationalNumber::operator>(int x)
{
    if(floatingPoint > (double) x)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

RationalNumber RationalNumber::operator+(const RationalNumber& r)
{
    RationalNumber result((numerator * r.denominator)+(r.numerator*denominator),denominator * r.denominator);
    result.reduceFraction();
    return result;
}

RationalNumber RationalNumber::operator+(int x)
{
    RationalNumber result(numerator * x,denominator);
    return result;
}
```

So here I have a class that is meant to represent rational numbers with overloaded operators that are intended for the purpose of carrying out arithmetic. However when in a main class performing the following:

```
RationalNumber medianCalculator(std::vector<RationalNumber*> &listOfRationalNumbers)
{
    std::sort(listOfRationalNumbers.begin(),listOfRationalNumbers.end());
    if(!(listOfRationalNumbers.size() % 2)){
        return ((RationalNumber(*listOfRationalNumbers.at((listOfRationalNumbers.size()/2) +1)) + (RationalNumber(*listOfRationalNumbers.at(listOfRationalNumbers.size()/2))) / 2));
    } else {
        return RationalNumber(*listOfRationalNumbers.at(listOfRationalNumbers.size() +1));
    }
}
```

First of all, it seems to generate an out of range exception, but more importantly it seems like operator overloading hasn't worked as the std::sort call doesn't seem to work or the arithmetic.

Comment: You are sorting pointers.. `std::vector<RationalNumber*>`, pass comparator as third param of `std::sort` in which you can dereference RationalNumber and use `operator<` for them.

Comment: Is there any reason why you store pointers in a vector instead of the rational numbers themselves?

Comment: When you'll follow the advice given here and have the vector hold the objects themselves, be sure to make your code const correct. `bool RationalNumber::operator<(const RationalNumber& r)` - here `r` is const and that's great, but the left hand side (`this`) is not. You need to const qualify the member function `bool RationalNumber::operator<(const RationalNumber& r) const`.

Comment: `operator<` should be `const` and so should many of your other operators

Comment: "Seems to" is vague. What exactly are you seeing? How did you come to that conclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely the operators are overloaded incorrectly. For example this code would produce unexpected result:

```
RationalNumber num(1, 1);
num *= 2;
// num is still 1/1
```

The correct implementation should be:

```
RationalNumber& RationalNumber::operator*(int x)
{
    numerator *= x;
    reduceFraction();
    return *this;
}
```

The rest of the methods should be implemented accordingly.